# AttributeError: module 'PyQt5.QtWidgets' has no attribute 'QMainWindows'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyqt

При попытке выполнить код:

```
import os
import sys

from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

import design


class App(QtWidgets.QMainWindows, design.Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    window = App()
    window.show()

    app.exec_()
```

Получаю ошибку:

> AttributeError: module 'PyQt5.QtWidgets' has no attribute 'QMainWindows`

Comment: У вас опечатка правильно `QMainWindow`

Comment: Спасибо большое

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка `AttributeError: module 'PyQt5.QtWidgets' has no attribute 'QMainWindows'` обозначает что у модуля `PyQt5.QtWidgets` нет элемента `QMainWindows`.

А причина в банальной опечатке, т.к. класс называется [QMainWindow](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmainwindow.html):

```
class App(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, design.Ui_MainWindow):
...
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, не заметил.

Comment: @ДимаСурок, если помогло с решением проблемы, отметьте вопрос как решенный

Comment: Да, простите за задержку. Stack Overflow говорил подождать перед отметкой, а потом я и забыл.

Comment: @ДимаСурок, все ок :)